# gnuplot steps with different stepwidths

Tags: gnuplot

I want to make a gnuplot graph of data with steps. Problem is that the data are binned and the bins have different widths. I can plot with boxes because there I can read in the width of the individual bins. I now want to get rid of the vertical lines of the boxes, i.e. simply plot steps. How can that be done with different bin widths?

Comment: `plot ... with steps`?

Comment: as in:
    plot [0:12][0:13] "steps.dat" title 'steps' with steps